# How to break out of loops in a Menu/Sub-Menu

Tags: java, loops, menu, submenu

I have a CRUD program that I am making that allows a user to create a `Shoppingcart` and input `Product` items into it. I have two menus: the basic CRUD screen that will contain an `ArrayList` of `Carts`, and a sub-menu that creates one `Cart`, allows a user to input `Product`s into it, and returns a `Cart` when it is finished. My problem is how to break out of the `while` loop in the submenu that continues to allow them to enter `Products` into the `Cart`, and return back to the CRUD main menu.

```
public static Cart subMenu() {
    boolean exit = false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Product myFruit;
    String name;
    int quantity;
    Cart myCart = new Cart();

    while (!exit) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an item and a quantity. Enter Q to return");
        name = input.next();
        quantity = input.nextInt();
        myFruit = new Product(name, quantity);
        myCart.addToCart(myFruit);
        System.out.println(myCart.getList());
        System.out.println(myCart.getTotal());
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
            exit = true;
        }

    }
    return myCart;
}
```

Comment: By using `break` :)))

Answer (score 0):

Use `break;` , as in the following example:

```
while (true) {
....
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
{
   break;
}

....
}
```

Source / More Info: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html